# How to get the value from Parameterized Test Fixtures?

Tags: c#, nunit

How to get the TestFixture parameter value as string and pass to Switch statement? I tried but can't solve the issue "Member 'ClassLibrary1.Browsers.browser1' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead". 
Init method should be a static because i used this in another class.

Code here:

```
[TestFixture("Chrome")]
public class Browsers
{
    public static IWebDriver webDriver;
    private static string baseURL = "https://www.google.com";
    private static string browser;

    private static string browser1;

    public Browsers(string browser1)
    {
         this.browser1 = browser1;
    }

    public static void Init()
    {
        switch (browser1)
        {
            case "Chrome":
                webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case "IE":
                webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            case "Firefox":
                webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
        }
        webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        Goto(baseURL);
    }
    public static string Title
    {
        get { return webDriver.Title; }
    }
    public static IWebDriver getDriver
    {
        get { return webDriver; }
    }
    public static void Goto(string url)
    {            
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    }
    public static void Close()
    {
        webDriver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to assign to a static field inside the constructor of the class. The constructor gets executed when creating an *instance* of the class. So you cannot do:

```
//This doesn't compile:
public class Browsers
{
    //snip
    private static string browser1;

    public Browsers(string browser1)
    {
        this.browser1 = browser1;
    }
    //snip
}
```

because there is no `this.browser1` field - `browser1` was declared as `static` so doesn't exist on an instance.

I think you were aiming for something like this instead:

```
[TestFixture("My String")]
public class When_Working_Up_A_Storm
{
    public When_Working_Up_A_Storm(string myString)
    {
        _myString = myString;
    }

    private string _myString;

    [Test]
    public void Magic_Happens()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("My String", _myString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As C# is telling you, you can't access an instance member from a static method. The reason for the problem in your case appears to be the fact that `Browsers` is not actually your test fixture, even though you placed the attribute on it. It looks like a static class containing various utility methods. Is that right?

The correct usage is to place the `TestFixtureAttribute` on a `TestFixture`, i.e. a class that contains tests. In that class's constructor, it can save the value of the argument, just as you have done. It can then initiate the correct browser instance either directly or using methods in a utility class.

You haven't explained what you mean by using the static `Init` method in another class, so I didn't go into that but I'll add to this answer if you explain it.